# Simple Python+OpenGL Transform Feedback

Tags: python, opengl

Closely following [this](https://open.gl/feedback) tutorial for transform feedback, but in python.  Given a simple transform feedback vertex shader,

```
#version 400 core
in float inValue;
out float outValue;

void main()
{
  outValue = 5*inValue+6;
}
```

and the surrounding python code to call it,

```
...

varyings = ctypes.create_string_buffer('outValue')
varyings_pp = POINTER(POINTER(c_char))(ctypes.cast(varyings, POINTER(c_char)))
gl.glTransformFeedbackVaryings(program, 1, varyings_pp, gl.GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS);

gl.glLinkProgram(program)
gl.glUseProgram(program)

vao = gl.glGenVertexArrays(1)
gl.glBindVertexArray(vao)

data = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.], dtype=np.float32)
vbo = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.nbytes, data, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

inputAttrib = gl.glGetAttribLocation(program, "inValue")
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(inputAttrib)
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(inputAttrib, 1, gl.GL_FLOAT, gl.GL_FALSE, 0, 0)

data = np.array([-1.,-2.,-3.,-4.,-5.], dtype=np.float32)
tbo = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, tbo)
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, data.nbytes, data, gl.GL_STATIC_READ)

gl.glEnable(gl.GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD)

gl.glBindBufferBase(gl.GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, tbo)

gl.glBeginTransformFeedback(gl.GL_POINTS)
gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_POINTS, 0, 3)
gl.glEndTransformFeedback()

gl.glFlush()

r_data = np.empty_like(data)
gl.glGetBufferSubData(gl.GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, data.nbytes, r_data)
print r_data
```

I get the output `[6. 6. 6. -4. -5.]`.  Thus it appears that `inValue` is constantly 0.  However, if I read back the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, I get my input data.  Have I bound the buffer to the vertex arrays incorrectly?  At no point are any `glError`s being raised, and the shader has no compile errors (error checking code omitted for aesthetic purposes).

Answer (score 1):

The same problem occurred to me. I am no expert in OpenGL but I think the problem is in type conversion from c-type buffer pointer to values. After some hits and trials, I was able to find a solution though.
It seems, that instead of the glGetBufferSubData function, glMapBuffer is accurate in terms of conversion.

The following lines of code can be implemented for obtaining the values.

```
bf = glMapBuffer(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE)
pointer = ctypes.cast(bf, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
arrayFromPointer = numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(pointer, (5,))

for ele in arrayFromPointer:
    print(ele)

glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)
```

Also, I found this [article](https://blog.karatos.in/a?ID=01250-406fc233-292b-46a4-bd5a-326baa3eef76) very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, and easy to miss due to dynamic typing.  This line here

```
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(inputAttrib, 1, gl.GL_FLOAT, gl.GL_FALSE, 0, 0)
```

should read

```
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(inputAttrib, 1, gl.GL_FLOAT, gl.GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code.

```
r_data = (c_float * data.size)()
gl.glGetBufferSubData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, data.nbytes, byref(r_data))
r_data = np.frombuffer(r_data, dtype=np.float32)
print(r_data)
```